# Find JSON field similarities in Laravel and MySQL

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have a table called videos. When I load a video, I need to find similar videos to it using a column called tags. The column is a JSON field that contains `tag_id`s from a different table called `tags` which I presume won't be of interest in this case.

When I load `video1` which has tags such as `[1,2,3,4]`, I should be able to find similar videos to it which have tags such as `video2 [2,3,4,5]`, `video3 [3,4,5,6]` and `video4 [4,5,6,7]` but it should not find `video5` which has the tags `[5,6,7,8]`.

I would also like to order the similar videos based on the number of tags they have in common with our video of interest. In this case, our results should be ordered as [video2, video3, video4] since video2 has 3 similar tags to video1 and video4 has only 1.

I have a rough clue that the solution could use `JSON_CONTAINS` but I'm not sure exactly how to implement it. Laravel methods are preferred as opposed raw SQL but that is just preference.

My logic flows like this:

```
$video = {id: 1, tags: [1,2,3,4]};
$similarVideos = Video::where(
    /* select other videos that have tags 1 or 2 or 3 or 4 */
);
```

Expected results:

```
$similarVideos = [
    {id:2, tags: [2,3,4,5]},
    {id:3, tags: [3,4,5,6]},
    {id:4, tags: [4,5,6,7]}
];
```

Comment: Try first a MySQL Verdi no and then convert it

Answer (score 2):

let's say that you are in the controller and retrieved the video, you now have  the tags array being [1,2,3,4].
You now need to build the query for the similar videos, a working solution is:

```
$videos = DB::table('videos')
            ->whereJsonContains('json-column-name', [1])
            ->orWhereJsonContains('json-column-name', [2])
            ->orWhereJsonContains('json-column-name', [3])
            ->orWhereJsonContains('json-column-name', [4])
            ->get();
```

Now is up to you to dynamically build the query above based on the length of the tags array.

> I would also like to order the similar videos based on the number of tags they have in common with our video of interest. In this case, our results should be ordered as [video2, video3, video4] since video2 has 3 similar tags to video1 and video4 has only 1.

I have not thought about this last part but i would probably solve it through laravel collection methods and not directly with a mysql query.

**update**

now we can group the results using laravel collections:

```
$tags=[1,2,3,4];
$grouped = $videos->mapToGroups(function (array $item, int $key) use($tags){
        $elementTags = $item['tags'];
        $commonTags = array_intersect($tags,$elementTags);
        $numberOfCommonTags = count($commonTags);
        return [$numberOfCommonTags => $item];
    });
dd($grouped);
```

the collection will have the results grouped by the number of common tags.

Again, not sure about a mysql only solution.

Comment: Any clue of the collection method of choice? The videos table could contain millions of records so our query could potentially leave out the most relevant results if we don't do it in the query, given that the final query could have some sort of pagination